# Maven disable plugin

Tags: java, maven

How can I execute `maven-jaxb2-plugin` plugin only on demand(e.g from command line or with soem configuration)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>com.example.action.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://localhost:8080/wsSecond/action.wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out maven profiles

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

and from the command line you'd activate a profile using

```
mvn -PprofileName <goals>
```